# Nginx + Xamp + SSL odd behavior

Tags: php, apache, ssl, nginx, https

I apologize if this has been brought up before but I've tried everything and now I'm stumped.

I setup XAMPP and then Nginx. I also set up Apache to use SSL. I set up Nginx to use SSL also. I attempted to set up a reverse proxy and now things are going wacky. I can go to https://rocco.tk/dashboard/index.html which shows that nginx is working and serving up my pages on port 80 from port 8080 using nginx on 443 using SSL.

But if you click on phpinfo, it downloads the page. BUT here is the thing.... If you go to http://rocco.tk/dashboard/phpinfo.php it works fine. If you use port 8080 and use apache only SSL, get an SSL error.  So I can only assume that there is an incorrect setting in regards to https and php. That setting I started to trace into Xampp under apache but then get lost.

My whole attempt is to set up a reverse proxy on apache with nginx so I can use nginx as the front end with SSL and allow apache to process php on that SSL.

Below is my nginx config files...

```html
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  off;

server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  rocco.tk;
 
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$
        {
            #root   html;
            root   C:/xampp/htdocs;
   index  index.html index.htm index.php;
            expires max;
        }
        #set default location
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
        #Adding location for phpmyadmin
        location /phpmyadmin {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/phpmyadmin;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
        }
 
        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8081;
        proxy_cache my-cache;
        proxy_cache_valid  200 302  60m;
        proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;
         }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
       #  location ~ /\.ht {
       #     deny  all;
       #  }
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  rocco.tk;

  ssl  on;
        ssl_certificate      C:\xampp\cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  C:\xampp\cert.key;

        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+EXP;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my httpd-ssl.conf

```html
Listen 8081

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4
SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4

SSLHonorCipherOrder on 
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:C:/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300


<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8081>

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName rocco.tk:8081
ServerAdmin rocco.paul@gmail.com
ErrorLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"

SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0


CustomLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

So I have apache listening to 8080. SSL listening on 8081. I have Nginx listening on 80 and SSL listening on 443.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ssl.conf for Nginx

## HTTPS server

```
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name Ip_addr;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert-bundle.key;

 location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Make sure you have placed both files *.crt* and *.key* files in **/etc/nginx/ssl/**

Also run below command to restart nginx service

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Comment: I'm not running php5-fpm though. I'm using Apache and php in xampp to run php scripts.

Comment: Thn you need to make sure ssl_certificate and ssl|_certificate_key url is enabled, openssl extension is configured and ssl.conf is getting included in configuration.

Comment: It is. I had that set up and it was working fine with https until I configured Nginx to listen on port 443 and 80, then configured Apache to listen on 8080 and 8081.